# Send data from server(nodejs) to client(ajax request)

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, mongoose

How do I send data from server to the client using nodejs?

So basically I call this function by clicking a button

javascript

```
function createStuff(tid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/create/',
        data: {tid: tid}
        success: function(id) {
            doStuff(id);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textstatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('text status ' + textstatus + ', err ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
};
```

This then handles the request

server

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    new Stuff({
        content: "random stuff"
    }).save(function(err, stuff) {
        Otherstuff.update({_id: req.body.tid}, {$push: {stuffes: stuff}}, {upsert: true}, function(err, mvar) {
            res.redirect(301, '/' + req.body.tid);
        });
    });
};
```

But I need to send along the newly created stuff._id with the res.redirect. The thing is I don't want to send it as res.redirect(301, '/' + req.body.tid + '/' + stuff._id) because I would have to do a whole new router which doesn't seem flexible. Also, when I do this request, the web page doesn't reload, which is just like I want it.

I tried using res.send(stuff._id), but I could only do it once (because the connection closes after it it seems). I'm using the following libraries: mongoose, jquery, express

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want to reply back to client with the original id you got in the request as well as the newly generated id.
What I didn't understand is, why are you using `redirect` if you don't want any page reload?

You could simply,

```
var obj = {
    tid: req.body.tid,
    _id: stuff._id
};

res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

And, the `ajax` success handler would be

```
success: function(data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    var id = obj._id;
    doStuff(id);
}
```

I guess this is what you want.

**Edit:**

As pointed by deitch, `express` itself converts the object into JSON string and adds a `Content-Type` header for JQuery to correctly identify and parse the string into JSON object. So no need to `stringify` and `parse` the data.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I was after! I'm new at node.js(and serverside programming in general), so I've been using redirect at the end of each router(though client hasn't been updating when I dynamically add content even with redirect) because I thought I needed to have some sort of response at the end of each router. If I don't need to send anything back, do I just have res.end(); then instead of res.redirect or res.send?

Comment: Glad to know it was helpful... :)

Comment: You don't even need to `JSON.stringify(obj)` if you are using express, it does it for you, just `res.send({a:1,b:2})`. Similarly jQuery will automatically convert it for you on the client side.

Comment: @deitch I think JQuery converts only if you `getJSON()` or add `dataType: 'json'` in the request.

Comment: @deitch Just checked, it works. Updating the answer. Thanks.. :)